# What is different between nuget.org and "Microsoft and .NET" in Online Section of Manage Nuget Packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

[image: Manage Nuget Package]
When you open Manage Nuget Packages, In online section there exists the "nuget.org" and "Microsoft.Net"

From what i understand is that "nuget.org" is a opensource packages that everyone can contribute and on "Microsoft and .NET" has only the Microsoft and .NET is only the packages that come directly from Microsoft. Is that right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nuget.org is the full list of available packages while "Microsoft and .NET" is a curated list of Microsoft-provided packages and Microsoft supported 3rd party libraries like jQuery.

See details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/nugetpackages.aspx).

Comment: Is the main reason to separate into 2 categories is that. If some project that require trustful and stability 3rd party. then it is a safe choice to use "Microsoft and .NET"